# CSS Changing color in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've got this table with clickable rows. In chrome they go blue when i hover over them, but when I do it in Internet Explorer, the row just becomes pale.

This is the CSS I'm using for the rows:

```
.clickableRow:hover {
    background-color: rgba(221,221,221,0.5);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
    background-color: #65a9d7;
}
```

I am using bootstrap and the code above.

Here's a JsFiddle if you want to know what it looks like: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaeunxt2/6/), If you check the fiddle in Internet Explorer aswell as Chrome you will see my issue.

If there's anything I missed, please ask me in the comments below.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get the correct color in Chrome/IE/Firefox?

Comment: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d); property is getting applied in chrome so you can see the  blue color, since firefox and IE engine is different. You have to try -ms- or -moz- properies for this.

Comment: @Ta-Zvi I tried adding that, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what my CSS class looks like right now: http://jsfiddle.net/s6bpvjqn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer isn't using webkit, so you have to use `-ms-...`

So this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpzt2tgh/) is just working in IE not Chrome or FF.
You can add all definitions, so `-webkit-...` `-ms-...` and `-moz-...`, to have it working in Chrome FF and IE.

Comment: I tried adding this http://jsfiddle.net/s6bpvjqn/ but it doesn't seem to work? I see it works in your JsFiddle though..

Comment: @DrCox for me its working in IE, but you have to add all the definitions everywhere, to have it working for all

Answer (score 1):

```
.clickableRow:hover {
background-color: #65a9d7;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
```

In your styles, need to change above 'background-color' value.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update this class in your CSS and it will work.

```
.clickableRow:hover {
  background: #65a9d7; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #65a9d7 0%, #3e779d 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #65a9d7 0%,#3e779d 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #65a9d7 0%,#3e779d 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#65a9d7', endColorstr='#3e779d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  color:white;
}
```

Also, I am sharing you the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaeunxt2/12/). Support: IE6 and onwards.
    Thanks